# How to configure Vue2 environment with Silex or other PHP framework

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, silex

I'm trying to configure Vue2 to run with Silex framework application on a local development environment. I created Vue application using CLI tool. Changed the open URL in `/build/dev-server.js` from `http://localhost/+port` to `http://localhost/` so `npm run dev` will open a Silex application. And added the following script url: `http://localhost:8080/app.js` in a php view.

Now when I run `npm run dev`, new tab in the browser is created with url `http://localhost/`. Vue application runs and I see my content (so webpack dev servers runs). The problem is it doesn't hot reload. When I check browser console I see that application constantly try to open `http://localhost/__webpack_hmr`.

So the question is, how to configure Vue development environment so it will work with Silex framework on a http://localhost:80 and webpack dev server with hot reload on http://localhost:8080 and still be able to run application by opening http://localhost/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `Laravel`, however, there isn't anything that's really specific to Laravel in my setup, so this should be the same for you with a few tweaks for wherever your files are stored:

First you will want to make sure your script is being loaded from `webpack-dev-server`, so:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/app.js"></script>
```

I actually have this placed in a conditional based on an environment variable, so it only does this in my development system and loads the bundled js in production.

Next you need to make sure your webpack dev config has `app.js` being served from `webpack-dev-server`. You can do that using `publicPath` which should point to the directory where your javascript files are being served from:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../public/js/'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/js/',
    filename: 'app.js'
},
```

For my purposes I've also set the path to `public/js` because that's where my `app.js` file is relative to the webpack config, so just set that to wherever your `js` files are being bundled in `silex`.

Now, you just want to configure dev server:

```
devServer: {
    hot: true, // this enables hot reload
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "../../../public"), // points to Laravel public folder
},
```

I then add a npm script to `package.json` using [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) - once again I'm pointing to the `public` folder for my php server:

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "php -S localhost:80 -t public,
  "hmr": "webpack-dev-server --env=webpack.dev",
  "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel hmr serve"
}
```

Now you should just be able to do :

`npm run dev`

to fire up both servers and then access your site from `http://localhost:80`

Comment: My package.json looks a bit different. Look at this: `"scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src"
  },` I want to keep this setup as close to stock configuration as possible while keeping it work as intended.

Comment: In vue webpack they are just running a node script to start the server and do some other initialising.It may be possible for you to run that particular dev process using [Api proxying](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html) which it looks like is being done through [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) to avoid CORS issues. Of course, that still has the requirement that you serve everything from the webpack dev server, not your PHP server, which means you can't use Twig and will need to mount your app via an `.html` file, which may be fine depending on your setup.

Comment: Thanks @craig_h, your answer pointed me out to the right direction and my solution was about 90% like yours so accepted yours instead.